# How to handle parameter-less and parameterized REST service on same URI

Tags: rest, uri

I am playing around with REST services in a Spring Boot environment. I have a question about the URI and naming conventions.

I have (currently) the following three mappings in my controller implementation...

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value= "/v1/accounts")
public List<Account> getAllAccounts() {
    return accountService.getAllAccounts();
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/v1/accounts/{accountId}")
public Account getAccount(@PathVariable int accountId) {
    return accountService.getAccount(accountId);
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/v1/accounts/")
public Account getAccount(@RequestParam("shortName") String shortName) {
    return accountService.getAccount(shortName);
}
```

These currently "work", but I have a question/concern about the getAccount(String) method. If I simply use the path "v1/accounts", the compiler seems to be unable to differentiate this from the URI for getAllAccounts(). So, I added the trailing '/', and the request now looks like...

```
/v1/accounts/?shortName=foo
```

However, it seems like the two requests should be...

```
/v1/accounts
```

and

```
/v1/accounts?shortName=foo
```

But, as already identified, changing the third request mapping to remove the trailing '/' results in compile-time errors.

Any input on either (a) how to eliminate the trailing '/' without running into compile-time errors, or (b) the advisability of incorporating the trailing '/' "just" to have both REST services exposed (I'm concerned about "what happens when the 3rd service is needed")?

Comment: Add Note: I can get the desired behavior for URI naming, but my solution results in having a list returned for all requests, even when a shortName is specified. This just "feels" wrong, so it's not an approach I'd like to take.

As of now, I'm using the trailing '/' for the parameterized version, but...

Any help/input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with one of our front-end devs, who said it's preferable to only deal with one return type (i.e., List vice List and Account), things simplified to...

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/v1/accounts")
public List<Account> getAccount(@RequestParam("shortName") Optional<String> shortName) {
    return (shortName.isPresent()) ? accountService.getAccount(shortName.get())
                                   : accountService.getAccounts();
}
```

I've seen some concerns about the use of "Optional" as a parameter type, but it does seem to (a) clean up the REST endpoint's URI, and (b) is not horrific in the controller implementation.

Unless someone points out the "big, unanticipated nightmare" associated with this approach, I think I'll run with this